# How do you find the longest array in a dictionary without referencing a specific key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, int[]> ret = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
    int[] a = {1,0,3,4,0};
    int[] b = { 3, 0, 9, 10, 0};
    int[] c = {2,3,3,5,0};
    ret.Add("Jack", a);
    ret.Add("Jane", b);
    ret.Add("James", c);

    int total = ret["Jack"].Length;

    Console.WriteLine(total);
}
```

To find the longest length I use:

```
int total = ret["Jack"].Length;
```

Is there a way to find the longest length without referencing a specific key?

Comment: `int total = ret.Max(t=>t.Value.Length);`

Comment: `dic.Values.Max(x => x.Length);` Also can call `Values` directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate through every key/value pair in the dictionary, check the length of the value, and remember the largest.

Luckily, there's a LINQ extension called `Max` that will do it for you:

```
int total = ret.Max(t => t.Value.Length);
```

Comment: Note: Max throws an exception on an empty sequence (or dictionary in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
int  longestVal = -1;

if(ret.Any())
{
    longestVal = ret.Values.Max(x => x.Length);
}
```

Comment: Is this answer? Or what? Hot does it help? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, this is obviously an answer!

Comment: The question is to find the longest length.
and it is the "longestVal" in my answer

Comment: Please spend some time in explanation of how this code work, what does it do, what is the origin of the question's author problem. Answers should not really contain only code, this is low-quality answer.